# Kafka Mirror Maker Startup Error

Tags: apache-kafka

I am trying to run Kafka Mirror maker on Kafka 1.0.1 and following are the configs in Target Cluster.

**source.config**

```
bootstrap.servers=XX.XXX.XX.XXX:9092,XX.XXX.XX.XXX:9092,XX.XXX.XX.XXX:9092
groupid=test-MirrorMaker-group
exclude.internal.topics=true
mirror.topics.whitelist=test
client.id=mirror_maker_consumer
```

**target.config**

```
bootstrap.servers=XX.XXX.XX.XXX:9092,XX.XXX.XX.XXX:9092,XX.XXX.XX.XXX:9092
acks=1
batch.size=100
client.id=mirror_maker_producer
```

And When I run the following command to start mirror maker on the target cluster .

./kafka-run-class.sh kafka.tools.MirrorMaker --consumer.config ../config/source.config --producer.config ../config/target.config --num.streams 2 --whitelist="test"

I get the following error

```
[2018-03-22 20:52:09,164] WARN The configuration 'groupid' was supplied but isn't a known config. (org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.ConsumerConfig)
[2018-03-22 20:52:09,164] WARN The configuration 'mirror.topics.whitelist' was supplied but isn't a known config. (org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.ConsumerConfig)
[2018-03-22 20:52:09,174] WARN The configuration 'groupid' was supplied but isn't a known config. (org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.ConsumerConfig)
[2018-03-22 20:52:09,174] WARN The configuration 'mirror.topics.whitelist' was supplied but isn't a known config. (org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.ConsumerConfig)
[2018-03-22 20:52:09,373] ERROR [Consumer clientId=null-0, groupId=] Attempt to join group failed due to fatal error: The configured groupId is invalid (org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.AbstractCoordinator)
[2018-03-22 20:52:09,375] FATAL [mirrormaker-thread-0] Mirror maker thread failure due to  (kafka.tools.MirrorMaker$MirrorMakerThread)
org.apache.kafka.common.errors.InvalidGroupIdException: The configured groupId is invalid
[2018-03-22 20:52:09,375] ERROR [Consumer clientId=null-1, groupId=] Attempt to join group failed due to fatal error: The configured groupId is invalid (org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.AbstractCoordinator)
[2018-03-22 20:52:09,377] FATAL [mirrormaker-thread-1] Mirror maker thread failure due to  (kafka.tools.MirrorMaker$MirrorMakerThread)
org.apache.kafka.common.errors.InvalidGroupIdException: The configured groupId is invalid
[2018-03-22 20:52:09,386] FATAL [mirrormaker-thread-1] Mirror maker thread exited abnormally, stopping the whole mirror maker. (kafka.tools.MirrorMaker$MirrorMakerThread)
```

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 3):

You have a typo. Replace groupid with group.id.

Comment: Oops. Thanks for catching that!